# Join into one list in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I had a DataFrame which I processed like so:

```
df = my_table[0]

df_position = df['Position'].replace({'-':','}, regex=True)
```

That gave me a result like this:

```
0  1,2,3,4
1  4,5,6,7
2  7,8,9,10
3  10,11,12,13
```

How can I put the data in a single list, like this?

```
[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,10,10,11,12,13]
```

Comment: You are replacing "-" with "," in the dataframe, but that doesn't make it being multiple elements, you need to somehow split it in different columns.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask] and [mre], and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. We [do not require](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721/) "thanks" and it does not belong in the question, and "any help is appreciated" [does not clarify the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236). Also, if your question is simply about how to process some data, it *does not matter how you got the data*; it only matters that we understand exactly *what the input is*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Your recent edit makes the post lose important information, such as their Python code. In fact, with the code we can see the dataframe is in reality a single column, with strings inside.

Comment: Rather than showing the original HTML, it would be more interesting to see *what was in `df` as a result of the `read_html` call*. Perhaps this original state of the `DataFrame` would make it easier to get the desired result.

Comment: @Gugu72 I restored the Python code because I did notice that as well from your comment. That said, yes, we should see the type information for the DataFrame as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can join the values together with `,` then split the whole thing on `,` and convert the values to `int`:

```py
[int(v) for v in ','.join(df_position).split(',')]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

If you want to operate directly on the dataframe, you could use this instead (joining and splitting on `-`):

```
[int(v) for v in '-'.join(df['Position']).split('-')]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions and its giving me errors. Here's the new question I opened showing your solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908536/how-to-save-html-table-data-cell-into-a-list-in-python?noredirect=1#comment128775419_72908536

Comment: @anagnam Why not just ask for clarification here, in comments on the answers?

Comment: @anagnam If you look at my code, I was operating on your `df_position` variable from your question, not the `df` directly. Please see my edit to use the df column instead

Comment: @Nick I tried your solution and Im still getting this error `line 12, in <listcomp>
    my_list = [int(v) for v in ','.join(df['Position']).split(',')]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1-2-3-4'`

Comment: @anagnam please look at my code carefully, the commas have been changed to hyphens when operating directly on the dataframe. See it working here https://ideone.com/Yox4wo

Comment: @Nick oh yes. my bad. I am using your old snippet thats why I got the error. But after using your updated snippet. It is now ok. many thanks!

Comment: @anagnam good to hear! I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 2):

Use `Series.str.split(',')` to split the values on comma, then call `explode` to make it vertically long, then call `to_list` to get list out of it. Using `df.iloc[:,0]` assuming that you are interested in first column's values.

```py
>>> df.iloc[:,0].str.split(',').explode().astype('int').to_list()

[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

Since you've already generated bound `df_position` to the specific column you want, you should also be able to use this.

```
df_position.str.split(',').explode().astype('int').to_list()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions and its giving me errors. Here's the new question I opened showing your solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72908536/how-to-save-html-table-data-cell-into-a-list-in-python?noredirect=1#comment128775419_72908536

Comment: @abagnam You just need to run this code on the version of your DataFrame that's already had the search-and-replace performed. I edited the variable name to make this clearer, based on the current form of your question.

Comment: @CrazyChucky your suggested solution has this errors `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1458, in _getitem_tuple
    tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 765, in _validate_tuple_indexer
    key = self._validate_key_length(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 812, in _validate_key_length
    raise IndexingError("Too many indexers")
pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Too many indexers`

Comment: @anagnam My mistake. I neglected to notice that `df_position` in your case is no longer a DataFrame, but a Series. You shouldn't need to do any indexing at all, so just `df_position.str.split(',').explode().astype('int').to_list()`.